# How can named expressions be interpreted in f-strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-interpolation, f-string, walrus-operator

I am trying to use named expressions inside a f-string:

```
print(f"{(a:=5 + 6) = }")
```

Returns:

```
(a:=5 + 6) = 11
```

But I am hoping for something like this:

```
a = 11
```

Is that possible, by combining the walrus operator and f-strings (so that I don't have to declare the variable `a` first in a separate step)?

Comment: The purpose of introducing the walrus operator was because in a few rare circumstances, its use can make code more readable. This is not one of them. Don't abuse it.

Comment: So it is not recommended to use walrus operators inside f-strings in general?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes exactly. I was wondering if this is possible, and also if it was an anti-pattern

Comment: I'd consider side effects inside an f-string a bad idea in general. It's much clearer to use two lines.

Comment: Point taken. I much appreciate the feedback

Comment: @GustavRasmussen the walrus operator assigns inside an expression, since there's nothing using `a` it's completely useless here. Likewise the `=` conversion sigil whose entire point is to print *the expression being f-printed* which is specifically *not* what you want here. Just use `print(f"a = {5 + 6}")`, it's shorter and does what you're asking for. Hell, you don't even need f-strings here, `print("a =", 5 + 6)` would do.

Comment: @Masklinn this is a small made up example, in the real code "a" is to be re-used

Comment: I suppose you use could use `print(f"a = {(a:= 5 + 6)}")`

Comment: @GustavRasmussen then it's fine to have it in the f-string, though you still won't have the formatting you're looking for  with `=` (because that's not how it works). And it seems overcomplicated when assigning outside the f-string... actually does exactly what you want: `a = 5 + 6; print(f'{a=}')` and is the exact same length. I don't get why "(so that I don't have to declare the variable a first in a separate step)?" is a thing if you want `a` to be declared either way, and you *do not* want to print the entire declaration expression.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 nice, that works. It certainly answers my question that this is possible. I learned from user2357112 that it is not recommended practice though.

Comment: @Masklinn yes I agree that separate assignment is more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
print(f"a = {(a:= 5 + 6)}")
# a = 11
```

Answer from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62444232/how-can-named-expressions-be-interpreted-in-f-strings/73191612#comment110435773_62444232)

Comment: If you are interested why parentheses are needed see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76901337/why-do-f-strings-require-brackets-around-assignment-expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about having `a` afterwards, you can `print(f"{5+6}")`

Otherwise, I don't think it's possible without some complex tricks

Comment: But my point is to do the assignment simultaneously