# Why do f-strings require parentheses around assignment expressions?

Tags: python, f-string, python-assignment-expression

In Python (3.11) why does the use of an assignment expression (the "walrus operator") require wrapping in parentheses when used inside an f-string?

For example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pathlib import Path

import torch


DEVICE = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

ckpt_dir = Path("/home/path/to/checkpoints")

_ckpt = next(ckpt_dir.iterdir())
print(_ckpt)
sdict = torch.load(_ckpt, map_location=DEVICE)

model_dict = sdict["state_dict"]

for k, v in model_dict.items():
    print(k)
    print(type(v))
    print(_shape := v.size())
    print(f"{(_numel := v.numel())}")
    print(_numel == torch.prod(torch.tensor(_shape)))
```

The code block above with `print(f"{_numel := v.numel()}")` instead does not parse.

What about the parsing / AST creation mandates this?

Comment: It's most likely expecting just a variable or, inside `(...)`, a more complete expression. For what it's worth, assigning a variable inside an f-string is pretty dirty and should be avoided.

Comment: Hint: can you think of another reason why `:` could be used inside `{}` in an f-string? (Something innate to the formatting system, not to do with the expression.)

Comment: Any particular reason you are attempting to perform variable assignment within an f-string? Assigning data and formatting data are very different operations and should generally be performed independently.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This behavior was explicitly specified in the [original PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) for the assignment expressions (aka the walrus operator).

The reason for this was to preserve backward compatibility with [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals). Before assignment expressions were added, you could already write f-strings like `f"{x:=y}"`, which meant "format `x` using the format specification `=y`".

Quoting [PEP 572 – Assignment Expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/):

> Assignment expressions inside of f-strings require parentheses. Example:
>
> ```
> >>> f'{(x:=10)}'  # Valid, uses assignment expression
> '10'
> >>> x = 10
> >>> f'{x:=10}'    # Valid, passes '=10' to formatter
> '        10'
> ```
>
> This shows that what looks like an assignment operator in an f-string is not always an assignment operator. The f-string parser uses `:` to indicate formatting options. To preserve backward compatibility, assignment operator usage inside of f-strings must be parenthesized. As noted above, this usage of the assignment operator is not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Both the colon `:` and the `=` have meanings inside f-strings, and the walrus `:=` does the same as just a colon `:`.

```py
x = 4
print(f"{x=}")  # prints "x = 4"
print(f"{x:10}")  # prints output in 10 spaces
print(f"{x:=10}")  # does same as :
```

The disassembly of `{x:=10}` just loads `=10` and passes it to the colon format operation.

```
  5           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 ('=10')
             10 FORMAT_VALUE             4 (with format)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: To clarify, the `=` specifies to put padding after the sign but before digits. Setting `x` to a negative value will show the difference between `f"{x:10}"` and `f"{x:=10}"`.